# Updating the Tweet This location after an Ajax call

Tags: jquery, twitter

I have a small routine which pulls out small snippets of news articles and a "Tweet This" button associated with the relevant article.

On the left of the page, I have a title of the article, clicking on it loads the main article to the right.

The problem I have however is that the "Tweet This" button always keeps the same URL as when the page loaded.

Is there anyway to dynamically change the location of the "Tweet This"?

I've tried using this code:

```
$('#content').find('a.twitter-share-button').each(function()
{
   var tweet_button = new twttr.TweetButton( $( this ).get( 0 ) );
   tweet_button.render();
});
```

But that's not working at all.

Answer (score 0):

How are you loading the content in the pane to the right? If it's just a normal link, might it be worth changing this to small ajax call which loads the content instead? That way you can also update your "Tweet this" button, simply by adding the relevant code into the `success` callback for your ajax call.

Alternatively, debug the code you have above: (1) how / where do you run it? (If it's running on initial page load, obviously it won't update right); and (2) check that `this` refers to the right thing.

Comment: Ben, the content on the road is loaded via an Ajax call and the code I've shown is indeed ran upon a Success callback.  I'm getting now errors in Firebug, just simply the URL is not updating.

Comment: OK. I'm not familiar with the `TweetButton` code you're using, but I would look at a couple of things: 1. Use `console.dir` to see if your `tweet_button` object is getting initialised as you expect, and has the correct settings. 2. If that looks OK, check whether something needs to happen after the `.render` call to ensure that the UI gets updated.